# Use of Factory pattern — how to implement it

Tags: object-oriented, design-patterns, typescript, factory-method

I am trying to figure out how Factory pattern works. I implemented it with TypeScript in this github repo: https://github.com/emilecollin/factory_pattern

Basically this is emulating spaceships gaming logic: the program will ask you to input in the terminal one of these options: "alien" or "zombie". With the provided input, the program will select on runtime the proper ship class to instantiate (AlienShip or ZombieShip), and a spaceships fight is mocked. The logic for the decision of which spaceship class to instantiate lives in a «factory method».

The abstract creator:

```
export abstract class AbstractShipFactory {
  public abstract makeShip(shipType: string): Ship;
}
```

The concrete creator:

```
export class EnemyShipFactory extends AbstractShipFactory {
  public makeShip(shipType: string): Ship {
    switch (shipType) {
      case 'alien':
        return new AlienShip();
      case 'zombie':
        return new ZombieShip();
    }
  }
}
```

The Product interface:

```
export interface Ship {
  name: string;
  damage: number;
  attack(): string;
}
```

And the Concrete Product class:

```
export class AlienShip implements Ship {
  private _name: string = 'alien';
  private _damage: number = 35;

  get name(): string {
    return this._name;
  }

  get damage(): number {
    return this._damage;
  }

  attack(): string {
    return '---->You are being attacked by ' + this.name + ' spaceship and got a damage of ' + this.damage;
  }
}
```

I'm now sure if I got it right. Still a bit confused about it. Any opinion of this code will be welcome!

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Because the desire to improve code is implied for all questions on this site, can you please update the question title to describe *what the code is supposed to do* rather than your concern about it?  Also good would be to add a bit more description to the first part of the question.  Tell us what the code is supposed to do and you'll get much better reviews. See [ask] for examples.

Answer (score 2):

1. There's no need to pass a `string` to `makeShip`. You should instead create 2 methods: `makeAlienShip` and `makeZombieShip`. This way as someone working on your code I can let my editor autocomplete and you won't have to write as much documentation.
2. As per above, having an `AbstractShipFactory` is an overuse of abstraction. What you could do is instead just make a `ShipFactory` that makes different types of ships: allied, enemy, neutral, zombie, pirate, alien etc.
3. Try to use template strings instead. It makes it much more readable especially if you're spitting out long messages. Like so:

```
return `---->You are being attacked by ${this.name} spaceship and got a damage of ${this.damage}`
```

4. Why is `attack()` responding with the string "You are being attacked by..."? This is extremely awkward and hard to understand: can a ship attack another ship? Or can a ship only attack the player? Maybe you could change the method name to `takeDamageFromShip()`. Even better would be to make a method `attack(ship: Ship)`

Think more about the relationships between objects in your program. You defined what a `Ship` is, but how does it interact with other objects in your program?

5. If zombie, alien, etc. are meant to be types of a `Ship`, add a `string` to your `Ship` interface instead.
6. Why are you not using a constructor to instantiate the properties of `AlienShip`? What if certain ships do more damage than others?

Comment: Thanks @taimoorahmad. About 1 and 2, I'm not sure if you are talking about factory method pattern or a simple factory. The former requires an abstract creator with a factoryMethod, and a creator that modifies it via polymorfism: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern.
About 3, 4, 5, 6, those issues have nothing to do with the question itself, sorry if they mislead you.